# Segmentation fault occuring when trying reverse a string

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition

So I have this function which is supposed to reverse a string and then return it

```
char *my_revstr(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while(str[j] != '\0') {
        j++;
    }
    j--;
    while(i < j) {
        k = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = k;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return (str);
}
```

But whenever I try to run it I have segmentation fault, and I'll be honest I don't very know why. I hope someone can help me fix this ^^.

Comment: the code seems fine to me, have you tried debugging it? also does it consistently crash with every test case?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The way you call `my_revstr` may be the problem. The `my_revstr` function itself looks correct to me.

Comment: There's a significant chance this is a duplicate of [**Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a `char *s` initialized with a string literal, but not `char s[]`?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a?rq=1)

Comment: va voir tes AERs plutot ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that you have a segmentation fault due to passing to the function a string literal something like

```
my_revstr( "Hello" );
```

You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

You should write like

```
char s[] = "Hello";
my_revstr( s );
```

Pay attention to that the variables i and j should have the type `size_t` because the type `int` can be not enough large to store sizes of strings.

The function can be defined for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below,

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * my_revstr( char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < --n; ++i )
        {
            char c = s[n];
            s[n] = s[i];
            s[i] = c;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    
    puts( s );
    puts( my_revstr( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
olleH
```

The function can be defined also for example the following way

```
char * my_revstr( char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Or you could implement the function using pointers. For example

```
char * my_revstr( char *s )
{
    char *first = s, *last = s;

    while ( *last ) ++last;

    if ( first != last )
    {
        for ( ; first < --last; ++first )
        {
            char c = *first;
            *first = *last;
            *last = c;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: If we want to be unnecessarily pedantic about it technically one should say that you "ought" not modify a string literal. Things that cause undefined behaviour aren't forbidden, they just make the program meaningless.